# What's the meaning of 'deflating mots' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context

I'm graduating in translation and one of my 2nd semester's works is a movie review about *Philomena*. I am stuck, however, at this part:

> (He's an) expert purveyor of deflating mots on any subject, including his own atheism: “I don’t believe in God and I think He can tell.”

I don't understand what "*deflating mots*" means. What's the meaning of "*mot*" in that context?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=define+mots
→
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mot

Answer (score 1):

It's French, meaning *word* ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mot#French))  and pronounced mo.  It's most often seen in English in the phrase *bon mot* ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bon+mot)) or *mot juste* ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mot%20juste)).

Answer (score 1):

A [***mot***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mot) is:

> a pithy or witty saying

So I'd suppose that by referring to '*deflating mots*', the author is talking about witty comments which tend to cause his opponents (or possibly his audience) to retract or to laugh at themselves—to 'deflate' their ego, in a sense.

Comment: Can I say he's sarcastic, then? After that, the text shows one of his quotes:
"I don't believe in God and I think He can tell.".

Anyways, thank you so much for the answer. It helped a lot!!

Comment: @LorenaRocha Perhaps, but I wouldn't say that a *deflating mot* is the same as a *sarcastic comment*. Some deflating mots might be sarcastic and some some sarcastic comments might be considered deflating mots, but they're not equivalent.

Comment: Hm, I see. I think in this context, Sixsmith (the "he") is being sarcastic. But I understood what you mean: not always a deflating mot is a sarcastic one and vice-versa.
Thank you very much. You saved my life, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

The word *mot* comes from 'bon mot' meaning a funny and clever remark. Here 'deflating mot' can mean a remark that is funny and clever and that also makes someone less confident or important.